# Python Parsing JSON List of JSON Responses

Tags: json, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a JSON File that contains multiple responses from an API request. I had to do this because of the size limit of the API call (limit was 1000, most calls actually had a total count in the tens of thousands).

The JSON File structure is like this:

```
[ List of Responses
  [ Response 1
    {  Object 1 
       "Key1" : Value,
       "Key2:": Value 
    },
    {  Object 2 
       "Key1" : Value,
       "Key2:": Value 
    }...
  ],
  [ Response 2
    {  Object 1
       "Key1" : Value,
       "Key2:": Value 
    },
    {  Object 2
       "Key1" : Value,
       "Key2:": Value  
    }...
  ]
] End of List
```

What I am trying to do is parse through this list of JSON responses and insert them into a DataFrame that I can write to a .csv or insert into a local db. The code I wrote to try to do this is:

```
with open('Data.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as handle:
    parsed = json.load(handle)

df_temp = []
column_name = "Key1"
for d in parsed:
    key1 = d.get([]).get('Key1', 'None')
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=key1,columns=column_name)
    df_temp.append(df)

final_df = pd.concat(df_temp)
```

However, that doesn't work because I am trying to use the .get call for a list which doesn't work. Can someone please point me in the right direction so I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The this is the answer I came up with:

```
for list in parsed:
    for d in list:
        key1 = d.get('Key1', 0)
        key2 = d.get('Key2', 0)
```